# NSView display code worked in Yosemite but not working in macOS Sierra

Tags: cocoa, appkit

When working with very large datasets (millions of items) my macOS app can sometimes take quite a long time to complete an action, in some cases even more than a minute. To let the user know that the app is working, I display the progress like a thermometer in a special view in the toolbar. This was originally developed a couple of years ago on Yosemite, and still works fine when run on 10.9 and 10.10. However, it does not work on Sierra (not sure about 10.11, don't have a system to test it on).

Here is what this looks like when it is working, showing 30% progress. The effect is a lot like the build progress displayed in the toolbar in Xcode (and like Xcode, other information is displayed in the banner, which is why I am not using NSProgressIndicator).

[image: Progress Indicator Banner]

The progress bar is displayed using a class called InfoBannerView, which is a subclass of NSButton. Here is the drawRect: method of this class (non-progress code that draws the background and text has been omitted for clarity). *progressValue* is a property that can be between 0 and 1, the method simply draws a rounded rectangle that fills a percentage of the width of the view, like a thermometer.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    NSRect bannerRectangle = [self bounds];
    {
        NSColor* progressColor = [NSColor colorFromHexRGBString:@"85ade1"];

        ... draw outline and background of banner

        if (progressValue > 0.0f && progressValue < 1.0f) {
            [progressColor setFill];
            NSRect progressRect = NSInsetRect(bannerRectangle, 1.0, 1.0);
            CGFloat progressWidth = progressRect.size.width * progressValue;
            progressRect.size.width = progressWidth;
            NSBezierPath* roundedProgressPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:progressRect xRadius:4 yRadius:4];
            [roundedProgressPath fill];
        }

        ... draw text on banner
    }
}
```

The code that takes a long time to run looks like this:

```
for {

    ... do stuff that takes a long time

    InfoBannerView * ibv = [windowController recordCountView];
    [ibv setProgress:value];
    [ibv display];
}
```

The line `[ibv display]` is supposed to immediately update the progress banner display, without waiting for the run loop. (Note: For performance reasons I don't really call -display every time thru the loop, but I've removed that code for clarity.)

If this code is run on Mac OS X 10.10, it works perfectly. The progress bar gradually fills the banner view as the work is performed.

However, if this code is run on macOS 10.12 Sierra, nothing is visible. I have determined that the drawRect: code *is* being called repeatedly, as it should be. It is being called for the correct object. All of the dimensions and values are correct. The only problem is -- nothing is drawn. (Drawing does occur properly when drawRect: is called during the course of normal view updates, however. By forcing *progressValue* to 0.3 I determined that that code draws properly during view updates also, in fact, that's how I made the illustration above.)

I tried running an old version of the application that was linked with the 10.10 SDK. Still no drawing when called via -display. It only works when run on 10.10 or earlier.

I was king of hoping that in writing this up the clouds would part and the answer would become obvious, but no such luck. I don't see anything relevant in the 10.11 or 10.12 release notes. Maybe I'm doing something dumb that has been wrong all along and I'm just lucky it ever worked? At this point, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Is the control a clickable button?

Comment: @Willeke at the time this post was written, InfoBannerView was a subclass of NSButton. However, it wasn't really using any NSButton functionality so last night I changed it to a subclass of NSView to see if NSButton was the problem. It wasn't. (The banner is clickable, clicks are handled in a mouseDown: method.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suggestion from Daniel Jalkut on Slack led to a solution. Replacing this line:

```
[ibv display];
```

with this:

```
[ibv setNeedsDisplay:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]];
```

resulted in the proper display happening, as shown here.

[image]

I think the original problem may be a bug in Sierra -- if the `-display` method doesn't draw immediately (which it did before), what is it for?